# php mysql , count rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following script :

```
 $queryUniqueEmail = "SELECT email FROM Applicant WHERE email = '".base64_encode($email)."';";
  $resultUniqueEmail = $db->query($queryUniqueEmail);
  $resultRowsEmails = $resultUniqueEmail->numRows();
if($resultRowsEmails == 0)
    $db->query($query);
  }
$resultRowsEmails->free();
}
$db->close();
echo "Finish!";
```

Basically verifies a an email is existing already in the db and if so the insert operation is skipped . Howver I'm getting the following error when I run it

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::numRows() in /var/www/html/asd.php
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: It looks like that base64 used as lame database escaping function, right? ;-) anyway, you're not using prepared statements, so using mysqli wrong way

Comment: you are right x 2 :) I got the data from some kind of xml which is not valid xml so to avoid the escaping hassle I just encoded in base64. The code that I'm using is not mine and I just try to "maintain" it . I personally don't use mysqli as due my low OOP skills I still use the old mysql method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method called `numRows` in the `mysqli_result` class.

There is a property, `num_rows`

```
$resultRowsEmails = $resultUniquEmail->num_rows;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: yes you are right, it's was so obvious and I didn't notice it . However now I'm getting  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function free() on a non-object

Comment: @Michael, you're calling `free()` on integer. Shouldn't it be `$resultUniqueEmail->free()`?

Comment: Because your calling it on variable containing amount of rows `$resultRowsEmails` instead of result object `$resultUniqueEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)